# Comic about an illegitimate prince with plant powers

Tags: story-identification, manga, powers, webcomics

It's a western historical theme with Princes, Emperors, Empresses, Dukes, etc. The main character is an illegitimate prince that was "abandoned" by his father, but is actually being hidden away to protect him from the Empress and nobles.

I believe some of his siblings find him, and befriend him, but his father finds out. His father finds out that the main character has plant powers inherited from his mother, instead of not having the royal powers. With the plant powers being incredibly rare, his father uses this as a chance to solidify his place in society, so he has a better way to protect him.

The father has the main character display his powers during a ball, where everyone goes from mocking him, to celebration. That's what I read up to before I lost it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When you say "visual" book, though, do you mean a comic, like a manhwa?

Comment: Er, I believe term is something like Webtoon? Manhwa may be what I'm thinking of. Also, thank you for the post corrections.

Comment: "Webtoons" are long-stripped digital comics, intended to be read on a digital screen, especially a smartphone. Most of them are Korean or Chinese in origin, so they're commonly found on manga websites, including dedicated publishers (e.g. webtoons.com). Do you recall where you read this?

Comment: I have no recollection of where I had read this. It's been well over a year, maybe even two at this point. I am even now searching everywhere, haha.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you Laurel!!! The art is not as great as I remember, but I'm not complaining. I've searched everywhere online, but haven't tried apps yet, guess that was my issue. Thanks a ton! Glad I got that link haha!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [The Villain that Embraces the Light](https://www.webtoons.com/en/challenge/the-villain-that-embraces-the-light/list?title_no=487704)

In [chapter 43-1](https://www.webtoons.com/en/challenge/the-villain-that-embraces-the-light/43-1/viewer?title_no=487704&episode_no=90) (in the middle of the events you describe), the main character, Petra discovers that he has earth powers by creating vines, unlike the rest of his family that has fire powers. Here his "shithead of a father" concludes it's because Petra's mother may have had earth powers:

[image]

After that ([chapter 51](https://www.webtoons.com/en/challenge/the-villain-that-embraces-the-light/51-1/viewer?title_no=487704&episode_no=124)), Petra's father has a birthday ball where he reveals Petra and his powers to the world.